# Vim find and replace all occurrences of a regex string

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file with a few thousand lines, and in this file I have some regex expressions...

The regex expressions are all over the place, and recently we've changed the expression and I need to update all of them.

I need to change all instances of: `[A-z -']+` with `[A-z \-']+`

so I tried doing `:%s/[A-z -']+/[A-z \-']+/g` but that replaced all occurrences of `[A-z -']+` with `[A-z -'[A-z -']+`

Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this substitution:

```
%s/\[A-z -']/[a-zA-Z '-]/g
```

It is wrong to use `[A-z]` as it will match many more characters than just `[A-Za-z]` and it is better to move hyphen to end position before closing `]` to get the regex right.

Comment: Thanks, that worked - Could you explain why `'-` will match hyphens but `-'` doesn't?

Comment: hyphen, if used in the middle of a character class is used as a range rather than literally. So your regex will match characters from space (0x20) to `'` (0x27)